# How to display images in PHP from MSSQL stored as varbinary(MAX) data type

Tags: php, sql-server

As stated in the title, I am having difficultly displaying images.  The code is pulling data from the database and displaying it as a bunch of meaningless characters.  The field is a varbinary(MAX) datatype.  I have tried using a JPEG header, as only JPEG files are allowed to save to the database, and echoing the $row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ati1q.jpg) variable ($row[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ati1q.jpg) is where the column where the image is stored) but it did not output anything.  Is there a standard way to display binary data from a varbinary(MAX) datatype as an image in PHP?

**PHP output**
[image]

**PHP code**

```
<?php
$servername = "MAINSERVER\SQLEXPRESS";
$dbname = "SqlFileStream";
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername) or die('Cannot connect to database');
$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, 'SELECT * FROM [VarbinaryTest]') or die(print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt))
{
echo '<br />';
echo 'Model: '.$row['model'];
header('Content-type: image/JPG');
echo $row['Data'];
}
sqlsrv_free_result($stmt);
?>
```

Comment: You can't send `<br /> Model: ....` along with binary data that represents the image. Also, the correct mime type is `image/jpeg`. You can ONLY send: 1) The header saying what the content is and set the transfer-encoding to binary and 2) echo the binary contents of a SINGLE image, you can't stick multiple images there.

Comment: To add to N.B.'s comments, I think you should seriously reconsider keeping your images in your database. Especially when working with PHP since it makes it very difficult to pull out and display those images. In ASP.NET MVC there are a bit more ways of handling this. Also, consider that only one image can be sent per response since (like N.B. said) the response has a mime type and each new image is a new query to the database and a new binary output as a response.